# How to implement inheritance using Twig in Phalcon?

Tags: twig, phalcon

Ok. I use Twig as a View engine and Phalcon version is 0.8

Code of adapter I got from this repository: [github](https://github.com/phalcon/incubator/tree/master/Library/Phalcon/Mvc/View/Engine) I made ​​a small modification in this code because I include Twig via composer. I will not describe these modifications because they are not significant.

So. My directory structure of view is very simple:

```
app
- views
--- index.twig
--- about
---- index.twig
```

Source of views/index.twig:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Phalcon PHP Framework</title>
</head>
<body>
    {% block content 'This is main page' %}
</body>
</html>
```

And source of views/about/index.twig:

```
{% extends "index.twig" %}

{% block content %}
    This is About page
{% endblock %}
```

Also, I have controller About (AboutController.php) with single method

```
public function indexAction()
```

it's empty.

Ok. Now. When I do a request for a page /about I expect to see there something like this:

```
This is About page
```

But I still see there content of views/index.twig:

```
This is main page
```

It's a bit strange to me. I reassign the block "content"!

I did some checking in the template views/about/index.twig adding extra characters out of the block and I received an error from Twig:

```
A template that extends another one cannot have a body in "about/index.twig"
```

So. Any ideas?

P.S. I think I should call in tpl views/index.twig method {{ content() }} but Twig knows nothing about this method.

Comment: Out of curiosity why don't you use Volt? Same syntax as Twig really and it is native to Phalcon.

Comment: One of the reasons is that I do not understand for what purpose was implemented function {{content ()}} in the template to display the contents of a child. Maybe I do not fully understand this ability, but I think it's nonsense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I was not good enough to read the documentation!

To solve my issue I had to use render levels of templates in View component: [official docs](https://phalcon-php-framework-documentation.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/views.html#control-rendering-levels)

To use the built-in export function in Twig and use a powerful mechanism of inheritance of this engine, 
we must set level render:

```
$view->setRenderLevel(Phalcon\Mvc\View::LEVEL_ACTION_VIEW);
```

In this case, the engine will immediately process the contents of the template action.

Answer (score 0):

Use {{ content|raw }}

Index.twig:

```
<h1>Title</h1>
{{ content|raw }}
```

Action view:

```
<h2>Title 2</h2>
```